# Figuring out GPU links topology programmatically with CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, multi-gpu

I'm trying to figure out link topology between GPUs.
Basically, do pretty much the same `nvidia-smi topo -m` does.

I've found a CUDA example `topologyQuery`, which basically calls 
`cudaDeviceGetP2PAttribute(&perfRank, cudaDevP2PAttrPerformanceRank, device1, device2)` for each pair of GPUs.

The results of running this example (I modified the output presentation a bit) are very confusing to me (after comparing to results of `nvidia-smi topo -m` on the same machine):

```
$ ./topologyQuery
        X       1       1       0       0       0       0       0
        1       X       0       1       0       0       0       0
        1       0       X       0       0       0       1       0
        0       1       0       X       0       0       0       1
        0       0       0       0       X       1       1       0
        0       0       0       0       1       X       0       1
        0       0       1       0       1       0       X       0
        0       0       0       1       0       1       0       X

$ nvidia-smi topo -m
        GPU0    GPU1    GPU2    GPU3    GPU4    GPU5    GPU6    GPU7    CPU Affinity
GPU0     X      NV1     NV1     NV2     NV2     PHB     PHB     PHB     0-95
GPU1    NV1      X      NV2     NV1     PHB     NV2     PHB     PHB     0-95
GPU2    NV1     NV2      X      NV2     PHB     PHB     NV1     PHB     0-95
GPU3    NV2     NV1     NV2      X      PHB     PHB     PHB     NV1     0-95
GPU4    NV2     PHB     PHB     PHB      X      NV1     NV1     NV2     0-95
GPU5    PHB     NV2     PHB     PHB     NV1      X      NV2     NV1     0-95
GPU6    PHB     PHB     NV1     PHB     NV1     NV2      X      NV2     0-95
GPU7    PHB     PHB     PHB     NV1     NV2     NV1     NV2      X      0-95
```

From https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html:

> cudaDevP2PAttrPerformanceRank: A relative value indicating the
>   performance of the link between two devices. Lower value means better
>   performance (0 being the value used for most performant link).

Why NV1 got rank 1? Why PHB got rank 0?
Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `cudaDevP2PAttrPerformanceRank` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what kind of system you are testing on (it looks approximately like output from a DGX-1).

With respect to this question:

> Why PHB got rank 0?

If you run the original `topologyQuery` sample code, you'll see (at least on DGX-1 like systems) that it does not print out a performance rank for every GPU pair.  From what I can see, it does not print out a performance rank for the places where `PHB` is indicated.  If you study the orginal code, the reason for this is clear: P2P is not supported on those pair combinations.  Your code, however, seems to print out a zero in these cases.  So I would say that is a defect in your code as compared to the original `topologyQuery` code, and it is leading to this question and your misunderstanding.  `PHB` did not get assigned rank 0 by the original code.  But your modified code does that.  So that's for you to answer.

> Why NV1 got rank 1?

With respect to the remainder, an `NV2` connection implies a dual-link NVLink connection between those 2 GPUs  (50GB/s per direction).  This would be the most performant kind of link (in that particular system), so it is assigned a link value of 0.

An `NV1` connection implies a single-link NVLink connection (25GB/s per direction).  This would be less performant than `NV2` so it is assigned a link performance value of 1.  Increasing performance numbers indicate decreasing link performance.

As an aside, if your intent is to do this:

> Basically, do pretty much the same `nvidia-smi topo -m` does.

You won't be able to do that strictly with CUDA API calls.

For reference, here is the `nvidia-smi topo -m` output and `./topologyQuery` output for a DGX-1:

```
# nvidia-smi topo -m
        GPU0    GPU1    GPU2    GPU3    GPU4    GPU5    GPU6    GPU7    CPU Affinity
GPU0     X      NV1     NV1     NV2     NV2     PHB     PHB     PHB     0-79
GPU1    NV1      X      NV2     NV1     PHB     NV2     PHB     PHB     0-79
GPU2    NV1     NV2      X      NV2     PHB     PHB     NV1     PHB     0-79
GPU3    NV2     NV1     NV2      X      PHB     PHB     PHB     NV1     0-79
GPU4    NV2     PHB     PHB     PHB      X      NV1     NV1     NV2     0-79
GPU5    PHB     NV2     PHB     PHB     NV1      X      NV2     NV1     0-79
GPU6    PHB     PHB     NV1     PHB     NV1     NV2      X      NV2     0-79
GPU7    PHB     PHB     PHB     NV1     NV2     NV1     NV2      X      0-79

Legend:

  X    = Self
  SYS  = Connection traversing PCIe as well as the SMP interconnect between NUMA nodes (e.g., QPI/UPI)
  NODE = Connection traversing PCIe as well as the interconnect between PCIe Host Bridges within a NUMA node
  PHB  = Connection traversing PCIe as well as a PCIe Host Bridge (typically the CPU)
  PXB  = Connection traversing multiple PCIe switches (without traversing the PCIe Host Bridge)
  PIX  = Connection traversing a single PCIe switch
  NV#  = Connection traversing a bonded set of # NVLinks
# ./topologyQuery
GPU0 <-> GPU1:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU0 <-> GPU2:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU0 <-> GPU3:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU0 <-> GPU4:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU1 <-> GPU0:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU1 <-> GPU2:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU1 <-> GPU3:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU1 <-> GPU5:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU2 <-> GPU0:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU2 <-> GPU1:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU2 <-> GPU3:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU2 <-> GPU6:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU3 <-> GPU0:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU3 <-> GPU1:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU3 <-> GPU2:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU3 <-> GPU7:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU4 <-> GPU0:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU4 <-> GPU5:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU4 <-> GPU6:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU4 <-> GPU7:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU5 <-> GPU1:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU5 <-> GPU4:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU5 <-> GPU6:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU5 <-> GPU7:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU6 <-> GPU2:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU6 <-> GPU4:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU6 <-> GPU5:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU6 <-> GPU7:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU7 <-> GPU3:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU7 <-> GPU4:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU7 <-> GPU5:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 1
GPU7 <-> GPU6:
  * Atomic Supported: yes
  * Perf Rank: 0
GPU0 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
GPU1 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
GPU2 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
GPU3 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
GPU4 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
GPU5 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
GPU6 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
GPU7 <-> CPU:
  * Atomic Supported: no
```